# Configure LDAP access info extracted from Wildlfy standalone.xml in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, ldap, wildfly

I'm developing a webapp using Spring MVC, Maven and Wildfly. I'm not using the web.xml to configure the datasources. My config is applied through Java classes.

I need to access the LDAP server info (url, base dn, username, password), which is in the standalone.xml located in the Wildfly configuration folder of the server, from the Java Spring Security configuration class. For security issues, I'm not allowed to code the LDAP info in the application.properties file. I don't know how to do it without using the web.xml. Any suggestions?

Here's what I have so far...

--standalone.xml (LDAP Config)

```
<security-domain name="MYDOMAIN">
  <authentication>
    <login-module code="LdapExtended" flag="required">
      <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
      <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://myurl:000/"/>
      <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple"/>
      <module-option name="bindDN" value="mybinddn"/>
      <module-option name="bindCredential" value="00000000000"/>
      <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="DC=bla,DC=bla,DC=bla"/>
      <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(sAMAccountName={0})"/>
      <module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="OU=Ludopatia,DC=iplyc,DC=gov,DC=ar"/>
      <module-option name="roleFilter" value="(member={1})"/>
      <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="cn"/>
      <module-option name="searchScope" value="ONELEVEL_SCOPE"/>
      <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords" value="false"/>
    </login-module>
  </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

--SecurityConfiguration.java

public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Value("${ldap.urls}")
private String ldapUrls;

@Value("${ldap.base.dn}")
private String ldapBaseDn;

@Value("${ldap.username}")
private String ldapUsername;

@Value("${ldap.password}")
private String ldapPassword;

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
    auth.ldapAuthentication()
    .userSearchFilter("sAMAccountName={0}")
    .groupSearchBase("ou=Ludopatia")
    .groupSearchFilter("member={0}")
    .contextSource()
       .url(ldapUrls+ldapBaseDn)
       .managerDn(ldapUsername)
       .managerPassword(ldapPassword);
}
```

}

--pom.xml (part in which the wildfly-maven-plugin is set)

```
<plugin>  
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>  
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>  
    <configuration>
             <jboss-home>${wildfly.home}</jboss-home>
             <modules-path>${wildfly.home}/modules</modules-path>
         <server-config>standalone.xml</server-config>
         <filename>${project.build.finalName}.war</filename>
    </configuration>  
</plugin>
```

--application.properties

```
ldap.urls=ldap://myurl:000/
ldap.base.dn=dc=bla,dc=bla,dc=bla
ldap.username=mybinddn
ldap.password=000000000000
```

Configured like this, it works perfectly. But I need to remove the LDAP info from the application.properties and directly take it from the standalone.xml, without using the web.xml.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can directly set these values from WILDFLY console (populate values into the standalone.xml file) or you can use https://www.vaultproject.io/ project.

Comment: Thanks. Could you instruct me a little more into how to set the value sinto the Wildfly console? What do you mean by populating the values into the standalone file? The values already are in the file, I just need to read them directly from there so that the method ldapAuthentication in the Spring Security Java configuration classes understands them. I cannot use the vault project you mention, because my company does not allow it. I have to figure it out as it is. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: did you find any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly set these values from WILDFLY console as system properties and they will be automatically populated into the standalone.xml file.

For that, kindly follow the following steps:

1. Enable the management console by adding an admin user (add-user.bat for Windows/add-user.sh for Linux).
2. After adding a user, access management console (http://127.0.0.1:9990/management).
3. It will prompt for username and password. Enter username and password.
4. Navigate to **Configuration -> System properties** and add as many as properties you want. They will be displayed in the configuration file.

   ```
   <system-properties>
     <property name="ldap.urls" value="ldap://myurl:000/"/>
     <property name="ldap.base.dn" value="dc=bla,dc=bla,dc=bla"/>
     <property name="ldap.username" value="mybinddn"/>
     <property name="ldap.password" value="000000000000"/>
   </system-properties>
   ```

To access these properties in your code, you need to access them as system properties such as

```
String ldapUsername= System.getProperty("ldap.username");
String ldapPassword= System.getProperty("ldap.password");
```

The only drawback of this approach is that the values of these properties will be visible all the time that's why I suggested [vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) project.

One more suggestion is to provide the encrypted values for ldap configuration and decrypt them after reading.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try this. But in fact, despite this helps erasing the ldap setting from the application.properties, I was hoping to use the ldap data which is already set in the standalone.xml. If I use this approach, I'd have the same configuration set twice: both in the standalone.xml AND in the Wildfly system properties. If you happen to know if I can just read the ldap setting directly from the standalone, without resetting in in the system properties, let me know. Thank you so much for your response!